# JavaScript Error - GET http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am making a messenger with PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript, and I'm using 000webhost.com to host it. My problem is, I get this error in the console: `GET http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php 404 (Not Found)`

Here is my index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Messenger</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .msg-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 0px 5px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    .msg-area {
        height: calc(100% - 102px);
        width: 100%;
        background-color:#FFF;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .msginput {
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: calc(100% - 20px);
        outline: none;
    }
    .bottom {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
        border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
        background-color: #EBEBEB;
    }
    #whitebg {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #FFF;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        opacity: 0.6;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    #loginbox {
        width: 600px;
        height: 350px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        background-color: #FFF;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        z-index: 1001;
        display: none;
    }
    h1 {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    button {
        background-color: #43ACEC;
        border: none;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 150px;
    }
    .buttonp {
        width: 150px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    .msg {
        margin: 10px 10px;
        background-color: #f1f0f0;
        max-width: calc(45% - 20px);
        color: #000;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .msgfrom {
        background-color: #0084ff;
        color: #FFF;
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 55%;
    }
    .msgarr {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 8px solid transparent;
        border-right: 8px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 8px solid #f1f0f0;
        transform: rotate(315deg);
        margin: -12px 0px 0px 45px;
    }
    .msgarrfrom {
        border-bottom: 8px solid #0084ff;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 45px;
    }
    .msgsentby {
        color: #8C8C8C;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 4px 0px 0px 10px;
    }
    .msgsentbyfrom {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 12px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="checkcookie(); update();">
<div id="whitebg"></div>
<div id="loginbox">
<h1>Pick a username:</h1>
<p><input type="text" name="pickusername" id="cusername" placeholder="Pick a username" class="msginput"></p>
<p class="buttonp"><button onclick="chooseusername()">Choose Username</button></p>
</div>
<div class="msg-container">
    <div class="header">Messenger</div>
    <div class="msg-area" id="msg-area"></div>
    <div class="bottom"><input type="text" name="msginput" class="msginput" id="msginput" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) sendmsg()" value="" placeholder="Enter your message here ... (Press enter to send message)"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var msginput = document.getElementById("msginput");

  function showLogin() {
    document.getElementById("whitebg").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("loginbox").style.display = "inline-block";
  }

  function chooseusername() {
    var user = document.getElementById("cusername").value;
    document.cookie = "messengerUname" + user;
    checkcookie();
  }

  function checkcookie() {
    if(document.cookie.indexOf("messageUname") == -1) {
      showLogin();
    } else {
      hideLogin();
    }
  }

  function getcookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
  }

  function sendmsg() {
    var message = msginput.value;
    if(message != "") {

      var username = getcookie("messengerUname");

      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
          console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
      }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","devconnect.comxa.com/update-messages.php?username="+username+"&message="+message, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see the website and error [here](http://devconnect.comxa.com) (The error is in the console)

I get another error, `Uncaught ReferenceError: update is not defined`, but I know why, so that error is fine.

Comment: if i hit http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php   i didn't get anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your hosting provider in injecting their own scripts on your pages:

```
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

Comment: Can I disable that?

Comment: @CarlLee No. You can contact your hosting provider support to confirm this though!